# Bg image issue - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I'm stuck in a simple animation code which has a no. of components in the container moves from top of the screen to a specific position. I have a bg image set in the UIID "AttempTitle" in the container consisting all the component. The problem is while all the components moves from top, the bg img is not seen until it reaches the specific position and it appears at last. How can I make the bg Image move along with the components.

I got another problem while doing it. I have a bg image in the title container. While the animation is taking place, the green bg image of the title container disappears for a second too. How that happened, I cannot figure out.

I have a video uploaded in the youtube incase you didn't understand the problem have a look at it.

https://youtu.be/6Or26wxnzUY

Code:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));

attemptIcon = theme.getImage("attemptIcon.png");
attempt1 = new Label(attemptIcon);
attempt2 = new Label(attemptIcon);
attempt3 = new Label(attemptIcon);
attempt4 = new Label(attemptIcon);
attempt5 = new Label(attemptIcon);

attemptContainer = BoxLayout.encloseX(attempt1, attempt2, attempt3, attempt4, attempt5);

Container titleContainer = new Container(new GridLayout(1));
titleContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(attemptContainer));
add(BorderLayout.NORTH, titleContainer);

attemptContainer.getParent().setUIID("AttempTitle");
attemptContainer.getParent().setPreferredW(screenWidth / 3);

questionAnswerContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Label a = new Label("questin answer");
questionAnswerContainer.add(a);

titleDialog = new Label("Yuppie!");
body1 = new Label("Let’s celebrate");
body2 = new Label("with another");
body3 = new Label("drink");
Button ok = new Button(theme.getImage("playIcon.png"));
ok.addActionListener(e -> {
    new Test(sm).show();
});

dialogContainer = (BoxLayout.encloseY(titleDialog, body1, body2, body3, ok));
dialogContainer.getAllStyles().setBgImage(theme.getImage("yuppieDialog.png"));

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, LayeredLayout.encloseIn(questionAnswerContainer, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(dialogContainer)));
titleDialog.getAllStyles().setMarginTop((dialogContainer.getPreferredW() / 3) + 30);

dialogContainer.getParent().setVisible(false);//using setHidden(true) gives same issue

Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        checkIfCorrect(Test.this);
    }
};
if (timer == null) {
    timer = new UITimer(r);
}
if (timer != null) {
    timer.schedule(5000, false, Test.this); //4 seconds
}
revalidate();
```

checkIfCorrect method:

```
public void checkIfCorrect(Form f) {
    dialogContainer.getParent().setY(-Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight());
    dialogContainer.getParent().setVisible(true);
    f.animateHierarchyAndWait(1200);
    f.setTransitionInAnimator(null);
}
```

toolbar code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
form.setToolbar(toolbar);
Container containerTitle = new Container(new BorderLayout());
toolbar.setTitleComponent(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(containerTitle, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ruslanLogo)))
//there r 4 buttons inside containerTitle container
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `animateLayout` instead of `animateHierarchy` start by setting the element you want as visible false then show. Then set it's Y to the right location set it to visible and do the animate layout.

The problem is that the background sizing/position of the `Container` doesn't work properly as a result of the animation.

Comment: Replacing animateHierarchy with animateLayout above in the code does nothing, doesnt animate at all. The components just appears.

Comment: Make sure you do that on the right container. Not on the form on the content pane or on the right child.

Comment: thankyou shai I made a container(added to mainform borderlayout center) and kept all the components inside it then animate that container & it worked. But the components slide down from below the toolbar. How to make it animate above toolbar? I have uploaded my toolbar code above as well.

Comment: Above the toolbar is a bit complicated because the Toolbar effectively resides in a different layer. Try using a layered toolbar or even not using a toolbar at all and just placing elements in the north.